# Gcloud command, can't specify "cloud-platform" scope when creating instance templates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

So I have a command like this that should create the instance template and give it the "cloud-platform" scope (which should give full access according to docs):

```
gcloud compute instance-templates create "webserver-template"\
 --source-instance=webserver --source-instance-zone=us-east4-c\
 --configure-disk=instantiate-from=custom-image,custom-image=projects/myproject-dev/global/images/webserver-image,device-name=webserver\
 --network=vpc-dev --scopes=cloud-platform
```

However, GCP seems to ignore that scope and assigns the default ones instead.  Am I missing something here?  I did go to an instance template in the GCP UI and created a new one based on it, and specified the option to "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs".  When I then use gcloud to describe that template, the scope is "cloud-platform" as it should be. I just can't figure out how to do it all in one gcloud command.

EDIT: I also tried "--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.  As you can see in my original question, I'm specifying the flag "--source-instance". And according to the docs:

> The name of the source instance that the instance template will be created from.
> You can override machine type and labels. Values of other flags will be ignored and values from the source instance will be used instead.

So the scopes flag was rightfully being ignored, and my source instance had the more limited scopes assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the **scopes** command-line option. Change to

```
--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it, but I tried that as well.  You should be able to specify the scope short name or full URL, but neither work for me.

Comment: Also, if the scope or params were incorrect, shouldn't the command tell me so?  That's what baffles me about this issue: no feedback from the command about the scope being incorrect or being ignored, it just quietly ignores this scope.

Comment: @kbosak - Turn on API logging. Add the command line option **--log-http**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just ran it with the logging enabled and got a ton of output.  What am I looking for in there?  I don't see scope being sent in any requests, only received in one.  And those received are the default scopes, not the one I specified. @JohnHanley

Comment: You will see the API call and the parameters with the returned response. You can then compare with the API to see exactly what is happening.